# How change the image of an image view when a button is pressed which is on that image view

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm new in iPhone, I've faced a problem. I've some images stored in an array. those images are shown on the Buttons as thumbnail an those buttons are on some image view to make some border to those images. now i want if any one press any button then that border image will change to thick border image, so that the user can understand which button he pressed

```
imgArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Accessories.png",@"Ariel.png",@"Average-Joe.png",@"Baseball-Bracelet.png",@"Basketball-Bracelet.png",@"Beaded-Flower-Charm.png",@"Beautiful-Vibrant-Bracelets.png",@"Believe-Bracelet.png",@"Black-Ribbon-Charm.png",@"Button-Bag.png",@"Cherry-Bomb-Bracelet.png",@"Christmas-Sacks.png",@"Christmas-Tree-Charm.png",@"Christmas-Trees.png",@"Clown.png",@"Cookie-Monster-Bracelet.png",@"Courage-Bracelet.png",@"Doctor.png",@"Dream-Rainbow.png",@"Duck.png",@"Elephant-Charm.png",@"Frozen-Charm-Bracelet.png",nil];

imageIndex = -1;
imgArryCount = [imgArray count];
divCount = imgArryCount/4;
modValCount = imgArryCount%4;
xAxis = 18;
yAxis = 18;
xxAxis = 41;
yyAxis = 41;

bgImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
        [bgImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bgBack960.png"]];
        [self.view addSubview:bgImage];

        scrlVw=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 55, 320, 395)];
        [scrlVw setDelegate:self];
        [self.scrlVw setPagingEnabled:YES];
        [self.view addSubview:scrlVw];

for (int i=1; i<=divCount; i++)
        {

            imgBackVw1 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(18, yAxis, 58, 60)];
            [imgBackVw1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image-box960.png"]];
            [self.scrlVw addSubview:imgBackVw1];

            imgBackVw2 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(94, yAxis, 58, 60)];
            [imgBackVw2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image-box960.png"]];
            [self.scrlVw addSubview:imgBackVw2];

            imgBackVw3 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(167, yAxis, 58, 60)];
            [imgBackVw3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image-box960.png"]];
            [self.scrlVw addSubview:imgBackVw3];

            imgBackVw4 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(240, yAxis, 58, 60)];
            [imgBackVw4 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image-box960.png"]];
            [self.scrlVw addSubview:imgBackVw4];

            imageIndex=imageIndex+1;
            imageBtn1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            imageBtn1.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, 48, 50);
            [imageBtn1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imgArray objectAtIndex:imageIndex]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [imageBtn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(imgBtnClckd:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [imageBtn1 setTag:imageIndex];
            [imgBackVw1 addSubview:imageBtn1];

            [imgBackVw1 bringSubviewToFront:imageBtn1];
            [imgBackVw1 setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

            imageIndex=imageIndex+1;
            imageBtn2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            imageBtn2.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, 48, 50);
            [imageBtn2 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imgArray objectAtIndex:imageIndex]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [imageBtn2 addTarget:self action:@selector(imgBtnClckd:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [imageBtn2 setTag:imageIndex];
            [imgBackVw2 addSubview:imageBtn2];
            [changedImgArry2 addObject:imageBtn2];
            [imgBackVw2 bringSubviewToFront:imageBtn2];
            [imgBackVw2 setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

            imageIndex=imageIndex+1;
            imageBtn3 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            imageBtn3.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, 48, 50);
            [imageBtn3 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imgArray objectAtIndex:imageIndex]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [imageBtn3 addTarget:self action:@selector(imgBtnClckd:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [imageBtn3 setTag:imageIndex];
            [imgBackVw3 addSubview:imageBtn3];
            [changedImgArry3 addObject:imageBtn3];
            [imgBackVw3 bringSubviewToFront:imageBtn3];
            [imgBackVw3 setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

            imageIndex=imageIndex+1;
            imageBtn4 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            imageBtn4.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, 48, 50);
            [imageBtn4 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imgArray objectAtIndex:imageIndex]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [imageBtn4 addTarget:self action:@selector(imgBtnClckd:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [imageBtn4 setTag:imageIndex];
            [imgBackVw4 addSubview:imageBtn4];
            [changedImgArry4 addObject:imageBtn4];
            [imgBackVw4 bringSubviewToFront:imageBtn4];
            [imgBackVw4 setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

            yAxis=yAxis+78;
        }

        if (modValCount!=0)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<modValCount; j++)
            {
                imgBackVw1 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xAxis, yAxis, 58, 60)];
                [imgBackVw1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image-box960.png"]];
                [changedImgArry1 addObject:imgBackVw1];
                [self.scrlVw addSubview:imgBackVw1];

                imageIndex=imageIndex+1;
                imageBtn1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
                imageBtn1.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, 48, 50);
                [imageBtn1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imgArray objectAtIndex:imageIndex]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [imageBtn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(imgBtnClckd:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                [imageBtn1 setTag:imageIndex];
                [imgBackVw1 addSubview:imageBtn1];
                [imgBackVw1 bringSubviewToFront:imageBtn1];
                [imgBackVw1 setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
                xAxis=xAxis+78;
                [scrlVw setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, divCount*78+86)];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            [scrlVw setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, divCount*78)];
        }

-(void)imgBtnClckd:(UIButton*)sender
{
    NSLog(@"ch...%@",changedImgArry1);

    NSString *str=[imgArray objectAtIndex:sender.tag];
    NSString *imgNameStr = [imgNameAary objectAtIndex:sender.tag];
    detailDesignObj.imgNameGl=str;
    detailDesignObj.getImgNAme = imgNameStr;
    detailDesignObj.getBtnIndex = sender.tag;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailDesignObj animated:YES];
}
```

any one can help me how can i do this?

Comment: one thing i've missed, the for loop portion is in a method which is called from view did load  [self getImages];  -(void)getImages

Comment: what do you want where do you want to set image in your imgBtnClckd there is no image view where you want to set your image give proper explination.

Comment: as you can see the buttons are on some image view, those image view contains some square border image. when user press that button the back image of that button will change to the thick border image, again if user press any other button then back image of that button will change to thick border image and previous button back image will changed to first image

Answer (score 0):

You are doing all good just need to add one more image for your touchUpInside state like you did for Normalstate for every button

```
[imageBtn2 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imgArray objectAtIndex:imageIndex]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[imageBtn2 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imgArray objectAtIndex:imageIndex]] UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this code on your view didLoad for intial image of imagView

```
        imageView1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];
        imageView2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"];
        imageView3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"];
```

And this code on button click

```
-(void)imgBtnClckd:(UIButton*)sender
    {
        imageView1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];
        imageView2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"];
        imageView3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"];

        if (sender.tag == 0)
        {
            imageView1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"darkBorder1.png"];
        }
        else if (sender.tag == 1) 
        {
           imageView2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"darkBorder2.png"];
        }
        else if (sender.tag == 2) 
        {
            [imageView3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"darkBorder3.png"];
        }
   }
```

Comment: with this method button image will change, but i want the image of image view which contains the buttons will change.

Comment: Now see my answer for changing image of imageView

Comment: the buttons and the image views are taken in for loop, as there are lots of images. so is there any short process to get the result?